# t-test and Granger Causality give conflicting results?

Tags: vector-autoregression, granger-causality

I have run a VAR(1) model with 3 endogenous variables on Eviews, where all time-series of interest are stationary. It might be important to mention that the 3 variables are the reverse logistic transformation of the correlation coefficient, the ln of positive semivariance of the benchmark, and the ln of the negative semivariance of the benchmark. Therefore, the semivariances are binary. For instance, when the return at time t is positive, the positive semivariance at time t is included in the regression, while a value of zero is assigned to the negative semivariance - and vice versa.

I extracted one of the 3 regressions of the VAR(1) model that I had estimated for the purpose of my analysis. The estimated VAR(1) model on Eviews, shows that the autoregressed variables are significantly different from zero at 1%. However, when I do the granger causality test, I cannot reject the null hypothesis of " x does not granger cause Y". I am confused! In a VAR(1) model, isn't the Granger causality test simply the t-test of the coefficients? If so then why am I getting conflicting results? (parameters significant at 1% when VAR(1) is estimated, but granger causality not significant). Either something odd is going on, or perhaps my understanding of granger causality test is flawed.